# Hide information below status line

Tags: vim, statusbar

I have `laststatus=2` and the `statusline` with a file name and stuff. I'd like to get rid of the information shown below the status in the command area. Setting `noruler` has no effect. The text looks e.g. after switching buffers like this:

```
"localization.cpp" [Modified] line 60 of 118 --50%-- col 1 ((1) of 9)
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

When switching buffers, Vim prints a message similar to the one in your question (though I don't recognize the exact format). The verbosity of this can be influenced via the `'shortmess'` option, but to completely turn this off, you'd have to override the buffer switch commands / mappings to use `:silent`.

It might also be a custom `:autocmd` that prints those messages. Can you reproduce this with a plain `vim -N -u NONE`, and does it disappear when you `:set eventignore=all`?!

Edit: Since this seems to be the default message from Vim, you can only workaround this by explicitly clearing it via an `:autocmd`:

```
:autocmd BufWinEnter * call feedkeys("\<C-\>\<C-n>:\<CR>", 'n')
```

Comment: `shortmess` looks to be already minified. `eventignore` does not influence it. If it can't be turned off by any option then I'll have to live with it. Thank you for your effort anyway!

Comment: Does this also happen in plain Vim, without any plugin (just your `laststatus=2`)? If not, you might find the problematic plugin by capturing a verbose log (`:set verbose=20 verbosefile=...`)

Comment: These are messages of the plain Vim so no plugin interferes.

Comment: Ah, that's too bad; you can then only workaround it. I've added one attempt to my answer.